# How to say a Service that a button was clicked in Activity

Tags: android, location, broadcastreceiver, ipc

I am developing an Android app for learning and practice. It is a gps tracker for sport activities.

I have a `Service` that implements a `LocationListener` to get position (latitude and longitude), altitude, etc, and send this information to the `Activity` by `sendBroadcast`. The `Activity` can show the current position in its layout because receive the information from `Service` through `BroadcastReceiver`.

Now, I need that the `Activity` inform to the `Service` that a pause button have been clicked so the `Service` does not send any location through `sendBroadcast`. What is the best option to do that? Another `BroadcastReceiver`? `Messenger`?

My `Serivce` is this:

```java
public class GpsTrackerService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = GpsTrackerService.class.getSimpleName();

// Action for location change and its extra data.
public static final String LOCATION_CHANGE_ACTION = "gpstrackerservice.LOCATION_CHANGE";
public static final String EXTRA_LOCATION_LATITUDE = "extra_location_latitude";
public static final String EXTRA_LOCATION_LONGITUDE = "extra_location_longitude";
public static final String EXTRA_LOCATION_ACCURACY = "extra_location_accuracy";
public static final String EXTRA_LOCATION_ALTITUDE = "extra_location_altitude";
public static final String EXTRA_LOCATION_TIME = "extra_location_time";

// Action for gps provider disabled and enabled.
public static final String LOCATION_GPS_PROVIDER_DISABLED_ACTION =
        "gpstrackerservice.GPS_DISABLED";
public static final String LOCATION_GPS_PROVIDER_ENABLED_ACTION =
        "gpstrackerservice.GPS_ENABLED";

// Contains if this service ir running or not.
private static boolean sIsRunning = false;

// Location manager and configuration.
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

// The location listener.
private android.location.LocationListener mLocationListener =
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

/**
 * An inner class for location listener.
 */
private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    /**
     * When loation is change it send via broadcast the information to the all registered
     * receivers.
     *
     * @param location
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);

        // Creates the intent, the location entity addint id to the extra and send de broadcast.
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        /*Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        es.rgmf.etroped.data.entity.Location locationEntity =
                new es.rgmf.etroped.data.entity.Location();
        locationEntity.setLatitude(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        locationEntity.setLongitude(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        locationEntity.setAccuracy(mLastLocation.getAccuracy());
        locationEntity.setGpsAltitude(mLastLocation.getAltitude());
        locationEntity.setBearing(mLastLocation.getBearing());
        locationEntity.setSpeed(mLastLocation.getSpeed());
        locationEntity.setTime(mLastLocation.getTime());

        bundle.putSerializable(EXTRA_LOCATION, locationEntity);*/

        intent.setAction(LOCATION_CHANGE_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_LATITUDE, mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_LONGITUDE, mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_ACCURACY, mLastLocation.getAccuracy());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_ALTITUDE, mLastLocation.getAltitude());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_TIME, mLastLocation.getTime());

        //intent.putExtras(bundle);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    /**
     * When provider is disabled then it sends via broadcast the information to all registered
     * receivers.
     *
     * @param provider The provider has been disabled (gps, for example).
     */
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);

        if (provider.equals("gps")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(LOCATION_GPS_PROVIDER_DISABLED_ACTION);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);

        if (provider.equals("gps")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(LOCATION_GPS_PROVIDER_ENABLED_ACTION);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

    // Initialize location manager.
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    // Prepares the location manager for updates and sets the flag sIsRunning to true. From this
    // moment it can says that service is running.
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListener
        );
        sIsRunning = true;
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();

    // Stop service in foreground.
    stopForeground(true);

    // It is not running.
    sIsRunning = false;

    // Remove listener.
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
}

public static boolean isRunning() {
    return sIsRunning;
}
}
```

Comment: see [bound services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

Comment: @pskink but what happen if Activity stop or destroy? The Service stop too, isn't It? Because of that I cannot to use a Bind Service.

Comment: so start your service before binding (`startService` + `bindService`)

Comment: read more about it on `Binding to a started service` section of the above link

Comment: @pskink I didn't know that that was possible... thanks.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: Another option rather than binding is to have a static boolean variable "isPauseClicked", and set it true once pause button is clicked. Then start checking it before sending broadcasts. But still binding is more professional